# How to set a boolean at controller level in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a controller class named WalletController, I also have another converter class that have attribute boolean. I am setting that boolean to true at every method in my controller. Is there a way to set that boolean at controller level instead of method level, so that boolean would only be true for this particular controller only?

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/api/wallet")
public class WalletController {
    

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WalletController.class);

    @Autowired
    private VoucherService voucherService;
    
    @Autowired
    MailManager mailManager ;
    
    @Autowired
    Converter converter;
        
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity saveTransaction(@RequestBody CreateTopupDTO createTopupDTO, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports = true;
        System.out.println("------------------"+httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
        return voucherService.createVoucher(createTopupDTO);
    }
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/withdraw", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity createWithdrawRequest(@RequestBody CreateWithdrawDTO withdrawDTO, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports =  true;
        return voucherService.createWithdrawRequest(withdrawDTO);
    }
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/currency", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getListOfCurrencies(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    //converter.supports = true;
          return voucherService.getListOfCurrencies();
    }
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/transactions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getTransactions(@RequestBody TransactionInfoDTO  transactionInfoDTO, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports = true;
        return voucherService.getTransactions(transactionInfoDTO);
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/transactions/properties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getPropertiesTransactions(  HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports = true;
        return voucherService.getPropertiesTransactions();
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/balance", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getBalance(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports = true;
        return voucherService.getBalance();
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/complete/balance", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getWalletBalance(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports = true;
        return voucherService.getWalletBalance();
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/complete/balance/v2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getWalletBalanceV2(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports=true;
        return voucherService.getWalletBalanceV2();
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/banks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getBanks(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports=true;
        return voucherService.getDepositBanks();
    }
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/properties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getProperties( HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports=true;
        return voucherService.getPropertyDetailsForTransactions();
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/valuationfee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity saveValuationFee(@RequestBody ValuationFeeDTO dto, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        //converter.supports=true;
        return voucherService.saveValuationFee(dto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't... If you share the same instance of the `Converter` between different classes this won't work and will lead to issues. Please describe what you are trying to achieve with this (and setting the value to true isn't what you are trying to achieve, that is an attempt at a solution).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am trying to encrypt the responses of my controllers, i wrote that boolean to tell which controllers should return encrypted responses and which should return plain responses. True means the response has to be encrypted.

Comment: Just create 2 instances of that converter, and inject the one you need into the controller. Don't start toggling settings. If you have multiple requests which change the value from true to false or vice-versa that suddenly applies to all requests!. As there is just 1 instance of the converter.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you give me a code example of it, or some link it will be helpful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custom bean for converter class (avoid @Component over the class) and inject it in controller when required.

For example:

Suppose you have a `Converter` class like this :

```
public class Converter {

    private boolean supports = false;

    public boolean isSupports() {
        return supports;
    }

    public void setSupports(boolean supports) {
        this.supports = supports;
    }

}
```

Create custom Converter bean in a `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {

    @Bean(name = "converterSupportTrue")
    public Converter beanOne() {
        Converter converter = new Converter();
        converter.setSupports(true);
        return converter;
    }
  
    @Bean(name = "converterSupportFalse")
    public Converter beanTwo() {
        Converter converter = new Converter();
        return converter;
    } 

}
```

Controller to test :

```
@Controller
public class FirstController {

    @Autowired
    private Converter converterSupportTrue;

    @GetMapping("/test/support1")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(converterSupportTrue.isSupports());
    }

}
```

Another controller to test ;

```
@Controller
public class SecondController {

    @Autowired
    private Converter converterSupportFalse;

    @GetMapping("/test/support2")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(converterSupportFalse.isSupports());
    }

}
```

You can use this bean throughout the application without writing boilerplate code.

Comment: @Noob Is this ok ?

Comment: I still cant get it, how will it set the supports value to true at a specific controller, i still have to go to method level

Comment: @Noob You don't have set anything on the controller.

Comment: @Noob Use this bean on controller to tell that end point to return a encrypted response.

Comment: this way it would be true for all the controllers present in the project, my aim was to set it true for specific controllers, at present i have to do it on method level but how can i set it on controller level?

Comment: @Noob Creating bean with true value doesn't mean that it will be true for all controllers. You have to specifically inject in the controller where you want.

Comment: Can you show me how to inject both with true and false?

Comment: @Noob Is this ok ?

Comment: I have injected the bean, it is encrypting all the responses from all the controllers

Comment: @Noob How are you implementing the code I'm not getting that ? Please provide more code details.